# Identify where preg_match occured

Tags: php, regex

How can I run the regex `/\Wtop\W/` and identify where that match occurs or what the non-alphanumeric (the \W) characters are?

I know I might want to do something like...

```
if (preg_match('/\Wtop\W/', $string)) {
  ...
```

But I'm still stuck on how to identify what the \W matched or where this match occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). Here's what you should do:

```
preg_match('/(\W)top\W/', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$position = $matches[1][1];
```

Here's a demo: http://www.ideone.com/vzSwI

Answer (score 1):

Use the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag to get the position of the match.

Enclose the `\W` in parentheses, capture the result (add an empty variable such as `$match`), then get `$match[1]` for the first `\W`, and `$match[2]` for the second.